# System of equations. How to automatically return the value 0 (in a matrix) for variables which don't occur in some equations (R-studio)?

Tags: r, variables, matrix

Giving an example:

> my_string<-"2a+5b-2c+2d=9; 3a-2b+1c-3d=34; -3a+3b+2c+4d=33; 2a+3b+4c+5d=125"

```
s <- my_string
p <- ";"
s2 <- gsub(p,"",s)
w <- nchar(s) - nchar(s2) + 1 
s1 <- my_string
p1 <- "[:a-z:]"
s3 <- gsub(p1,"",s1) 
k <- (nchar(s1) - nchar(s3) )/w +1
my_string<-strsplit(my_string, ";")
my_string<-unlist(my_string)
my_string<-trimws(my_string)

for (i in 1:w) {
  print(noquote(paste0(my_string[i])))
}
sp2 <- strsplit(my_string, "=")
b <- as.numeric(sapply(sp2, '[[', 2))
sp3 <- lapply(lapply(sp2, '[[', 1), function(s) gsub("([-+])([[:alpha:]])", 
"\\11\\2", s))
sp3 <- lapply(sp3, trimws)
sp3 <- lapply(sp3, function(s1) sub("^([[:alpha:]])", "1\\1", s1))
A <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sp3, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"
[[:alpha:]]")))))

x <- cbind(A,b)
x
```

The output of this program is this matrix:

```
                   b
[1,]  2  5 -2  2   9
[2,]  3 -2  1 -3  34
[3,] -3  3  2  4  33
[4,]  2  3  4  5 125
```

It works correct. But a problem comes when in at least one equation there won't occur some variables which exist in other equations. In such case the program will not work.
My question is: How to modify it that for example this system of equations:

> my_string <- "2a+5b-2c=9; 3a-2b-3d=34; -3a+3b+2c+4d=33; 2a+4c+5d=125"

will give this output:

```
                   b
[1,]  2  5 -2  0   9
[2,]  3 -2  0 -3  34
[3,] -3  3  2  4  33
[4,]  2  0  4  5 125
```

(every column stands for the next variable, if in any equation don't occur some variables it should return the value 0 for the particular positions)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
str_split(my_string, "; ") %>%
           magrittr::extract2(1) %>%
           map_df(~ .x %>%
                     {
                      x1 <- str_extract_all(., pattern = "[0-9-]+")[[1]]
                      x2 <- c(str_extract_all(., pattern = "[a-z]+")[[1]], "e")
                      set_names(as.list(x1), x2)
                       }
                       %>%
                     as_tibble) %>%
           select(a, b, c, d, e) %>%
           mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(replace(., is.na(.), 0))))
 # A tibble: 4 x 5
#     a     b     c     d      e
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  2.00  5.00 -2.00  0      9.00
#2  3.00 -2.00  0    -3.00  34.0 
#3 -3.00  3.00  2.00  4.00  33.0 
#4  2.00  0     4.00  5.00 125
```